# Salesforce Mobile SDK Community Registration

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am developing a mobile application for one of our client using Salesforce SDk. I haven't found any documentation regarding the community registration vai Salsforce SDK. Is this possible? 
Because when i complete the registration from "Not a member" link the page is still loading in the webview , not getting redirected to the application ( to mobile). Is there any way to accomplish registration via SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/networks_customize_login.htm) link provides all configuration items that you need to have in place to use Communities with the Salesforce Mobile SDK. Depending on the kind of user license, you also need to have appropriate permissions (such as API enabled for Portal users) - refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176604&language=en_US) link.

- SDK does not provide any explicit support for self-registration.

Comment: Hai Gaurav, Thanks for replying. My salesforce is side working properly. I have configured the community. The issue is with SDK integration , any idea about the callback after user registration?

Comment: What have you currently set it to? Are you using any SSO auth mechanism?

Comment: No Gaurav, i have checked just self- registration option. Did self registration supports in SDK? i haven't seen any documentation regarding this. Do we need to do any other auth mechanism for this? Please suggest

Comment: AFAIK, the SDK does not provide any explicit support for self-registration.